# Opening a file into a different tab

Tags: java, swing, editor, jtabbedpane

I am a writer that is looking to create my own editor to keep up with not only the story itself but also the characters. The character data will be in the second tab, while the story is in the first. Is there a way to open the character data directly to the second tab when it is opened? I was going to try to use a project file to open both files at once. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you load additional files, create a new editor panel (or whatever it is you're doing) and use JTabbedPane.addTab()

Comment: thanks. I'll try that when I get off work this evening.